# Override the signature of a method with an extension

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I have the following case:

A generic interface

```
public interface AbstractObject {
  ...
}
```

A some specific classes who extends the interface

```
public class RealObject implements AbstractObject {
  ...
}

public class TrueObject implements AbstractObject {
  ...
}
```

A generic abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractManager extends OtherManager {

  public abstract AbstractObject get(AbstractObject obj);
  public abstract AbstractObject put(AbstractObject obj);

}
```

I need a class that extends AbstractManager and implements its the methods, using extensions of the class AbstractObject, something like this:

```
public class ConcreteManager extends AbstractManager {

  @Override
  public TrueObject get(TrueObject trueObj){
    ...
  return tobj;
  }

  @Override
  public TrueObject put(RealObject realObj2){
    ...
  return tobj;
  }

}
```

Is it possibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to narrow the return type of the method when overriding a method, but you can't narrow the type of the parameter.

The solution is to make your class generic, so you can specify the type of the method's parameter with generics.

Add generic type parameters to your abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractManager<
        T1 extends AbstractObject, T2 extends AbstractObject>
        extends OtherManager
{
    public abstract T1 get(T1 obj);
    public abstract T1 put(T2 obj);
}
```

Then you can specify what `T` is in your subclass:

```
public class ConcreteManager extends AbstractManager<TrueObject, RealObject>
{
    @Override
    public TrueObject get(TrueObject trueObj) {/* Implementation */}
    public TrueObject put(RealObject realObj2) {/* Implementation */}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you wrote it. Remember that you have to be able to use an instance of a subclass anywhere you can use the superclass, so the subclass's return type must be *at least* as specific as the superclass's (you're good here), and its parameter type must be *at most* as specific as the superclass's (and this is your problem). Code using an `AbstractManager` needs to be able to pass any old `AbstractObject` to `get` and `put`, so you can't require something more specific in `ConcreteManager`.

Java Generics offers a way to "customize" an interface to a particular type; for an example, see the Collections types like `List`. This is a bit trickier, and may or may not be worth the additional complication, depending on your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this using one method and *instanceof* operator

```
public class ConcreteManager extends AbstractManager {
    public AbstractObject get(AbstractObject trueObj) {
        if(trueObj instanceof TrueObject) {
            return trueObj;
        } else if(trueObj instanceof RealObject) {
            return trueObj;
        } else {
            // type unknown
            return null; 
        }
    }
}
```

Generics are more complicated and not needed here.

Comment: Generics are *less* complicated than this solution, which (a) doesn't implement the type constraints required in the question; (b) is longer than the same thing expressed in Generics; and (c) requires all subclasses to be known ahead of time.